# Cassandra can not delete role or user which in the role or user list

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

```
create ROLE testROLE with PASSWORD = 'test';
create ROLE testROLE with PASSWORD = 'test';
```

`list ROLES` shows the roles successfully.

```
DROP ROLE testROLE;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="testrole doesn't exist"
DROP ROLE test1;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="test1 doesn't exist"
```

Image of CQLSH output.

[image]

The role showed in the list but can not be deleted.
How this can happen???

Comment: What is the output if you run `DROP ROLE IF EXISTS testrole;`?

Comment: By chance, are you using Windows?

Comment: @Aaron Linux 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Nathan nothing shows, after I execute that one, the roles list still keep the same. it's strange.

Answer (score 2):

When not quoted, role names do not preserve case, as you can see from the list roles output. If your role names are case-sensitive, you'll need to enclose them in double quotes (like you would for keyspace or table names).

Did you edit the output you pasted? I ask because you shouldn't be able to run the same CREATE ROLE statement twice as shown. If so, was anything else elided? I suspect that you were able to successfully drop the role once, but not a second time (that's the expected behaviour & what I'm seeing).

Comment: I also tried the testrole and testROLE. they show the same error info.

Comment: This exactly was the solution to my problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.2/NEWS.txt#L634): When migrating from Cassandra 2 to Cassandra 3, once all nodes have been migrated, one should delete the legacy tables `system_auth.users`, `system_auth.credentials` and `system_auth.permissions`.

If not done, Cassandra will write new roles to the new table, but try and read roles from the old one, which gives the behaviour described in the question.